# Merge and split repeated values into serveral columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two database, one has names of people and the second have the error type they did.

```
table1=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Daniel','Rosa','Toni','Lena'],
                    'age':[25,24,32,29]})
table2=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Daniel','Daniel','Toni','Toni','Toni','Lena'],
                     'Error': ['type1','type75','type7','type1','type3','type1']})
```

I would like to get new table with the name, th age and the error, but,
**I would like to get seperated columns for each error the person did.**

I have merged the two tables like this:

```
merge=pd.merge(table1,table2[['Name','Error']], how='left',left_on='Name',right_on='Name')
```

but the result is  table when each name repeats the number of errors it has:

```
>>>
    Name    age  Error
0   Daniel  25  type1
1   Daniel  25  type75
2   Rosa    24  NaN
3   Toni    32  type7
4   Toni    32  type1
5   Toni    32  type3
6   Lena    29  type1
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
>>>
    Name    age  Error_1  Error_2 Error_3
0   Daniel  25  type1     type75
2   Rosa    24  no error  
3   Toni    32  type7     type1    type3
6   Lena    29  type1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reshape `table2` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for DataFrame with multiple columns and then add to `table1` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), last replace possible missing values for first column `Error_1` by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with dictioanry and then for all missing values by empty string second `fillna`:

```
df = (table2.set_index(['Name', table2.groupby('Name').cumcount().add(1)])['Error']
           .unstack(fill_value='')
           .add_prefix('Error_'))
print (df)
       Error_1 Error_2 Error_3
Name                          
Daniel   type1  type75        
Lena     type1                
Toni     type7   type1   type3

merge=table1.join(df, on='Name').fillna({'Error_1': 'No error'}).fillna('')
print (merge)
     Name  age   Error_1 Error_2 Error_3
0  Daniel   25     type1  type75        
1    Rosa   24  No error                
2    Toni   32     type7   type1   type3
3    Lena   29     type1
```

Change order of operation is possible, main difference is output of `Name` and `age` column is sorted in final `DataFrame`:

```
merge=pd.merge(table1,table2[['Name','Error']], how='left', on='Name').fillna({'Error': 'No error'})
print (merge)
     Name  age     Error
0  Daniel   25     type1
1  Daniel   25    type75
2    Rosa   24  No error
3    Toni   32     type7
4    Toni   32     type1
5    Toni   32     type3
6    Lena   29     type1

df = (merge.set_index(['Name', 'age', merge.groupby(['Name','age']).cumcount().add(1)])['Error']
           .unstack(fill_value='')
           .add_prefix('Error_')
           .reset_index())
print (df)
     Name  age   Error_1 Error_2 Error_3
0  Daniel   25     type1  type75        
1    Lena   29     type1                
2    Rosa   24  No error                
3    Toni   32     type7   type1   type3
```

Answer (score 1):

The second table which is non-unique shout be made wide using `pandas.DataFrame.pivot`. Once the data is transformed in wide format, merge it with original table -

```
import pandas as pd

table1=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Daniel','Rosa','Toni','Lena'],
                    'age':[25,24,32,29]})
table2=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Daniel','Daniel','Toni','Toni','Toni','Lena'],
                     'Error': ['type1','type75','type7','type1','type3','type1']})

#Reshape the data to make it unique on name
table2['rank'] = table2.reset_index().groupby(['Name'])['index'].rank().astype(int)
table2 = table2.pivot(index='Name', columns='rank', values='Error').reset_index()
table2.columns = ['Name'] + ["Error_"+str(x) for x in table2.columns[1:]]

table = table1.merge(table2, on = 'Name', how='left')
```